# Mathematica can not interpret parentheses correctly

Tags: formatting, input, input-forms

[image]

I want to sum up four terms but Mathematica does not interpret the parentheses correctly. In the picture, in second line there is only one term that starts with `1/12`, and in the first line there are three terms that start with `1`, `1/18`, and `1/36`. In second line, I believe there is absolutely nothing between `1/12 lambda_0^2 h_0^5` and the parenthesis afterwards, and I mean `1/12 lambda_0^2 h_0^5` times the parenthesis afterwards. But somehow in the output mathematica adds a closing parenthesis after `1/12 lambda_0^2 h_0^5` and a beginning parenthesis after `1+` in the first line, as shown in the first line of the output.

I have tried adding `*` between `1/12 lambda_0^2 h_0^5` and the parenthesis afterwards but it does not work. It seems like there is no way I can let mathematica interpret this expression correctly. Does anyone have any idea what might be the cause and how to avoid it?

(Originally I copied all the terms in the expressions from previous outputs, and I suspected that different formats of fractions (`a/b` or a over b) may have caused the problem, so I have changed every fraction to one line, but still Mathematica insists on adding a non-existent parenthesis that messes everything up.)

Plain text:

```
1+1/18 *((N1+2) Subsuperscript[\[Lambda], 0, 2] Subscript[h, 0])*(1/512 (k^2 \[Pi]^4) \[Epsilon])+1/36 ((N1+8) Subsuperscript[\[Lambda], 0, 2] Subsuperscript[h, 0, 3])(1/384 k^2 \[Pi]^4 \[Epsilon]^2+(10-3 EulerGamma+Log[64]+3 Log[\[Pi]/k^2])/(768 k^2 \[Pi]^4 \[Epsilon]))+1/12 Subsuperscript[\[Lambda], 0, 2] Subsuperscript[h, 0, 5](1/2048 k^2 \[Pi]^4 \[Epsilon]^2+(4-EulerGamma+Log[4 \[Pi]/k^2])/(1024 k^2 \[Pi]^4 \[Epsilon]))
```

Raw Input Form:

```
1 + HoldForm[(1/18)*((N1 + 2)*Subscript[\[Lambda], 0]^2*Subscript[h, 0])*((1/512)*(k^2*Pi^4)*\[Epsilon]) + 
 HoldForm[((1/36)*((N1 + 8)*Subscript[\[Lambda], 0]^2*Subscript[h, 0]^3)*((1/384)*k^2*Pi^4*\[Epsilon]^2 + 
     (10 - 3*EulerGamma + Log[64] + 3*Log[Pi/k^2])/(768*k^2*Pi^4*\[Epsilon]))) *  (Plus[HoldForm[(1/12)*Subscript[\[Lambda], 0]^2*Subscript[h, 0]^5]])]]*((1/2048)*k^2*Pi^4*\[Epsilon]^2 + (4 - EulerGamma + Log[4*(Pi/k^2)])/(1024*k^2*Pi^4*\[Epsilon]))
```

I guess you can already see from these two forms that in plain text it is `+1/12` while in raw input form it is `*  (Plus[HoldForm[(1/12)...`

Sorry for the mess in the code: I don't know how to keep it recognized as code by this editor while making it indent well.

Comment: Please include your code as plain text in addition to the picture, so people here can copy it and paste it in their own notebooks to play with it. See [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Also note that [`N`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) has built-in meaning and should not be used as a variable. It is generally advisable to avoid using single-letter uppercase names for your own variables, as they may conflict with built-ins.

Comment: It looks like you have an invisible symbol somewhere around the problematic spot. Try copying the code and pasting it into a string or text editor. Or select the cell and go to the menu entry Cell – Show Expression, it may show you some invisibles that you're not aware of.

Comment: Output of your plain text looks good on version `"13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`, whereas raw input form delives the output you get.  What version are you using?

Comment: I believe I am using  "13.0.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)"; I just installed it a couple days ago

Comment: Indeed the plain text gives the correct output; does this mean I always have to convert each expression to plain text first before evaluaing it?

Comment: You have a nested `HoldForm` here. If you take your raw input form and apply `ReleaseHold` twice to it, it works.

Comment: Where should I put "ReleaseHold"? I applied it twice to the whole expression in raw input form and it did not work

Comment: Oh, I see... It seems like I have to manually convert it to a form (input, rawinput, standard, tranditional) to see the hidden "HoldForm". This is so tricky!

Comment: The issue is... where did `HoldForm` come from in the first place?  Presumably somewhere earlier in your code.  If you get rid of it from there, you won't have a problem here.

Comment: `HoldForm` is used instead of `Hold` for the purpose of it being hidden in `StandardForm` (see the documentation).  "Holding" an expression keeps it from being altered by further evaluation. `HoldForm` is produced by very few functions in Mathematica, the `Trace` functions being the only ones to come to mind at present. The presumption is that you added it for some reason (perhaps for the wrong reason?).